# Is it possible to use #ifdef like checks in assembler?

Tags: cross-platform, assembly, platform-independent

I have tested a bit of assembler on Linux using the AT&T syntax. One thing that struck me was that the book I was reading was written from a 32-bit standpoint. Thus, all sizes would have to be changed to the correct 64-bit versions for me. Or I could (which I did) assemble the code using the **--32** flag for **as** and the **-melf_i386** flag for **ld** when linking. I have also adapted some of the code and to run on Windows under Cygwin.

But that got me thinking. Is there a way to do **ifdef** like checks in assembler to do one thing if I'm on **Windows** and another under **Linux** and also handle **32** vs **64** bit that way? For example to have a **.globl _start** under Linux and a **.globl _main** under Windows.

Or is this handled by checking before assembling and having different source files to assemble based on the result of the checks?

I.e. **foo_linux.s** and **foo_windows.s**

If so, how do you overcome that fact that you will not know which **.s** files you will use, and thus have to include, when you are creating your program?

For example, say that we have a **socket_linux.s** and a **socket_windows.s**. They both present an identical interface but do the OS specific work associated to sockets. But when I work with the sockets in my program I will not know if I need the Windows or Linux version included. So I would be kinda screwed :)

So how is this handled in Assembler? In C++ for example I could include my **socket.h** and **socket.cpp** and wrap all the Linux and Windows specific code in **#ifdef** statements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use GCC to compile your files and name them `.S` (with uppercase S) or `.sx`, it will pass them through the preprocessor before invoking the assembler.

From [the docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html):

```
file.s
   Assembler code. 
file.S
file.sx
   Assembler code which must be preprocessed.
```

You can add `-v` to the command line to see how the various sub-processes are invoked.

Answer (score 3):

in MASM (.asm), you can use `ifdef`, `ifndef` and the likes, as:

```
ifdef X64
endif
```

Comment: Related: NASM/YASM doesn't predefine many macros to let you detect platforms easily with [`%ifdef` / `%endif`](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html).  See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124484/how-to-detect-architecture-in-nasm-at-compile-time-so-that-i-could-have-one-sour) for some platform-detection tricks.

Answer (score 1):

When writing for different platforms you can define some macro for loading target specific files:

FILE `target.h`

```
#if defined(__arm__)
    #define target "arm"
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
    #if defined(_WIN64)
        #define target "win64"
    #else
        #define target "linux64"  // all non-Win share the same calling convention
    #endif
#else
    // 32bit defs
#endif
```

Then you can include target specific files with the macro, two string literals successively get one single literal:

```
#include "target.h"

#include "target_specific_code_" target ".h"
```

It includes one of these files:

```
target_specific_code_arm.h
target_specific_code_win64.h
target_specific_code_linux64.h
...
```

**EDIT:**

Like this, you can also define target specific assembler instructions for later use in inline assembly:

```
#ifdef ...
    #define ASM_PP_LOAD_WORD "movi "
#else
    #define ASM_PP_LOAD_WORD "mov "
#endif
```

or as macro

```
#ifdef ...
    // when using intel assembler there is a different
    // order of parameters
    #define ASM_PP_LOAD_WORD(a, b) "movi " #b ", " #a
#else
    #define ASM_PP_LOAD_WORD(a, b) "mov " #a ", " #b
#endif
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion for using string pasting to generate include-file names.  I wouldn't have guessed that would work.  x86-64 Linux and Windows do use different calling conventions, unfortunately, so you do need different macros if you want to call your functions directly from C/C++ with the standard ABI.