# Getting undefined reference to "_printf" error for assembly code despite using gcc linker

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, linker, nasm

I am trying to follow the exercise in the book PC Assembly by Paul Carter. http://pacman128.github.io/pcasm/

I'm trying to run the program from 1.4 page 23 on Ubuntu 18. The files are all available on the github site above.

Since original code is for 32bit I compile using

nasm -f elf32

for first.asm and asm_io.asm to get the object files. I also compile driver.c

I use the linker from gcc and run

```
gcc -m32 -o first first.o asm_io.o driver.o
```

but it keeps giving me a bun of errors like

undefined reference to '_scanf'
undefined reference to '_printf'

(note _printf appears instead of printf because some conversion is done in the file asm_io.asm to maintain compatibility between windows and linux OS's)

I don't know why these errors are appearing. I also try running using linker directly

```
ld -m elf_i386 -e main -o first -first.o driver.o asm_io.o -I /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
```

and many variations since it seems that its not linking with the C libraries.

Any help? Stuck on this for a while and couldn't find a solution on similar questions

Comment: Include explicitly the C standard library with `-lc` parameter (to the compiler, or to the linker)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linux doesn't prepend `_` to names when mapping from C to asm symbol names in ELF object files<sup>1</sup>.

So `call printf`, not `_printf`, because there is no `_printf` in libc.
([Or in a PIE executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126328/cant-call-c-standard-library-function-on-64-bit-linux-from-assembly-yasm-code) like `gcc` makes by default on most distros, `call printf wrt ..plt`)

Whatever "compatibility" code did that is doing it wrong.  Only Windows and OS X use `_printf`, Linux uses `printf`.

So either you've misconfigured something or defined the wrong setting, or it requires updating / porting to Linux.

---

Footnote 1: In ancient history (like over 20 years ago), Linux with the `a.out` file format did use leading underscores on symbol names.

---

Update: the library uses the NASM preprocessor to `%define _scanf scanf` and so on, **but it requires you to manually define `ELF_TYPE` by assembling with `nasm -d ELF_TYPE`**.

They could have detected ELF32 or ELF64 output formats on their own, [because NASM pre-defines `__OUTPUT_FORMAT__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124484/how-to-detect-architecture-in-nasm-at-compile-time-to-have-one-source-code-for-b/29891660#29891660).  Someone should submit a pull-request to make this detection automatic with code something like this:

```
%ifidn __OUTPUT_FORMAT__, elf32
  %define  ELF_TYPE 32
%elifidn __OUTPUT_FORMAT__, elf64
  %define  ELF_TYPE 64
%endif


%ifdef ELF_TYPE
...
%endif
```

Comment: I was just gonna point out that in the asm_io.asm file the author included (includes some functions used for debugging) it has a section
%ifdef ELF_TYPE
  %define _scanf scanf
  %define _printf printf

but then I took a closer look and in the comments it said to compile with 
nasm -f elf -d ELF_TYPE asm_io.asm

and uh... yea that solved the problem lol, stupid me. 

So i guess thanks haha, and for the very prompt answer. I'll put this as the right answer

Comment: @ackbar03: They could have used `%ifidn __OUTPUT_FORMAT__, elf32` (and also check for `elf64`) to avoid you having to manually do anything on the NASM command line.  Someone should send in a pull request.  [How to detect architecture in NASM at compile time to have one source code for both x64 and x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29891660)

Comment: Well, probably there's no `_printf` code in the C library, but just to cope with legacy code, probably it should be :)  Let's vote for inclussion!!! :)

Comment: @LuisColorado: I don't think it makes any sense to double the size of the dynamic symbol table (slowing down dynamic linking on every process startup) by having a legacy alternate name for every symbol in libc and libm.  (And where do you stop?).  It wouldn't even be possible: `_exit(2)` and `exit(3)` are separate functions.  See [Syscall implementation of exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46903180)

Comment: @PeterCordes, almost completely in agreement, both problems you describe can be solved, but I agree with you that making a specific implementation to be "portable" is some kind of contradiction.  Implementations have their own particularities.  The GNU approach of taking off the front `_` in identifiers allows to access the, _until then,_ hidden identifiers without it from the high level C.  The same criteria (or reasoning) to introduce it can be used to eliminate.

Comment: @LuisColorado: interesting point.  I'd never considered why Linux/ELF changed to not prefix with `_`.  While commenting the other day, I wondered if it was just for minor file-size reasons (1 fewer byte in every symbol).  Maybe also better behaviour for string comparisons if a mismatch can sometimes be detected in the first byte instead of 2nd?  Or better properties for a radix trie or other data structure that holds a set of identifiers.  You can still create symbol names you can't use as C variables, e.g. containing `.`.  Or use local labels that don't appear in the object file at all.