# How to call asm function in C program?

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

I try calling asm from a C program

Here is my code:

```
// Template C to x86 call
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

extern void asmhello();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    asmhello();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my asm code:

```
; assembly part using x86-64

section .data
msg db "Hello World",13,10,0
section .text
bits 64
default rel ; to handle address relocation
global asmhello

extern printf
asmhello:

    sub rsp, 8*5 ; caller
    mov rcx, msg1
    call printf
    add rsp, 8*5
    ret
```

I try running it in VS 2022

the error says..

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol asmhello referenced in function main
```

The error also says

```
function definition for 'asmhello' not found.
```

Comment: Have you added .asm or .obj file to your "solution"?

Comment: the file name is in "test.asm" and i already configured in the property to have an output file of "test.obj"

Comment: Your error talks about a symbol `sum` but your code does not have that. Please make sure you post the code you are using. Also your asm code is for `nasm`, did you set up your build to run that for you? And then, as @fukanchik asked, did you add it to the link step?

Comment: Ok. then the function name in asm (!) should  be `_asmhello`. Note `_` in the beginning. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753691/underscore-prefix-problem-in-x86-calling-nasm-function-from-c-function-works

Comment: it still display the error :(

Comment: yes I it is the code that I am using and I already fix the image of the error

Comment: Please post the error message as text, not as image.

Comment: @fukanchik: This is 64-bit code, so no, there shouldn't be a leading `_`, as stated in the Q&A you linked.

Comment: Google _"use assembly code with visual studio 2022"_ and follow one of the tutorials. I didn't try any of them though...